# Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in error on live site only

Tags: php

I have a test (localhost) website and a live site that use the same PHP code. I am getting the following error ONLY on my live site (doesn't happen on the localhost version using the same codebase.

> Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted
>   to string in .... on line 486.

Note - line 486 is this line within the foreach loop - any ideas why it isn't working on live but ok for localhost?

```
$out .= sprintf("<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>", $error['title'], $error['description']);
```

Code Block

```
public function getErrorTable()
{
    $support_email_link = "<a href='" . $this->support_email . "'>" . $this->support_email . "</a>";

    $out = '<div style="width:100%;min-height:380px;text-align:center;"><p style="font-size: 30px;">Error encountered <i class="fa fa-times" style="color:#CC0000;"></i></p><span>Please contact ' . $support_email_link . "</span><br><table id='error_table'><thead><th>Error Title</th><th>Description</th></thead><tbody>";

    foreach ($this->errors as $error) {
        $out .= sprintf("<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>", $error['title'], $error['description']);
    }

    $out .= "</tbody></table></div>";

    return $out;
}
```

Comment: just show what `var_dump($error);` is outputing. then i will able to give a right answer

Comment: My guess is that you are catching an error that you are not getting in your dev environment

Comment: Modify your PHP config so it shows all errors and warnings (or add **error_reporting (E_ALL);** to the start of your file(s))

Comment: It looks like either $error['title'] or $error['description'] (or both) is an object of type stdClass and so when sprintf tries to turn it into a string, the error is thrown. As @A-2-A, said, using var_dump($error) will tell you the type of the variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what `$this->errors` is containing when `getErrorTable` is called, but the error message indicates that either `$error['title']` or `$error['description']` is an object, rather than a string.

Now, this can be caused by many things, from different PHP configuration to a different execution flow on your website. This is hard to tell from just this snippet. The easiest way for you to debug this issue is to simply `print_r($error)` in your foreach, or `error_log(print_r($error, true))` if the website is in production and you don't want to just dump information to your visitors (which is probably a bad idea!).